# Wordpress: singe-tag template not working

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, taxonomy

i created a custom taxonomy called faq

```
$post_type = array(
    "faq"
);

$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'FAQ Categorieën', 'taxonomy general name', 'feiken' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'FAQ Categorie', 'taxonomy singular name', 'feiken' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Zoek in FAQ categorieën', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'Alle FAQ categorieën', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'FAQ Categorie aanpassen', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'FAQ Categorie updaten', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Nieuwe FAQ Categorie toevoegen', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'FAQ Categorieën', 'textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'faq' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'faq', $post_type, $args );
```

I have created archive-faq.php because faq is also an custom post type. The taxonomy is just for giving categories to the custom posts.

My problem is that I can't get any template like tag.php, or taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{tag}.php to work. it skips straight to index.php

What I want is that when you click on a tag on the archive page it goes to a new template where it shows all the posts related to that tag.

Comment: can you also post the code which generates the faq CPT?